# i want to set canonical href as full/path/with/category/product-url? in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1.3

I want to set canonical href as `full/path/with/category/product-url`?

> right now it will use only demain.com/product.html

Comment: anybody know in which file generate this canonical product url ? any idea

Comment: Canonical tag coming from `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/view.php`